# Adding script to lacij graph

Tags: clojure

From what I can understand the lacij library does not have support for the "script" tag. So I was trying to include a javascript src.
 When I try the following

```
(def new-graph (lacij.edit/build old-graph))
(def element (tikkba.util.dom/elements (:xmldoc new-graph) tikkba.dom/svg-ns [:script {:src "myscript.js"}]))
(println element)
(tikkba.util.dom/append-child (:xmldoc new-graph) element)
```

I get a " The node (type: 1, name: script) cannot be inserted, since the document node already has a node of type 1. " exception and not I am not sure why. "Script" node is not in the Dom in the first place.
 I'd appreciate any kind of help here.

Comment: I am currently using Lacij (inturn tikkba and analemma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - so I've got something for you to try. I've not used lacij or tikkba before, so I'm not sure if it's idiomatic. Mutating an xml document in this way in Clojure makes me feel a bit uneasy - but I guess that's just the way when doing java interop.

Anyway, here goes:

First build the graph using lacij:

```
(use 'lacij.edit.graph)
(def g 
    (-> (graph) 
        (add-node :a "A" :x 50 :y 20) 
        (add-node :b "B" :x 50 :y 100) 
        (add-edge :a-to-b :a :b)
        (build)))
```

Then create and add the script element using tikkba:

```
(use 'tikkba.utils.dom)
(def element 
    (elements 
       (:xmldoc g) 
       tikkba.dom/svg-ns 
       [:script {:src "myscript.js"}]))

(append-child (document-element (:xmldoc g)) element)

(spit-xml "test-with-script.svg" (:xmldoc g))
```

Script will be appended at the end of the document.

**Reasoning**

I guess before tikkba was complaining about adding at the top level of the XML file. There was already a document tag (`<svg>`) in the xml document and XML files can only have one root element. The code above instructs tikkba to add *within* the svg element instead of at the top level. It seems to work.

Comment: You, sir, have fixed the problem. As I see the mistake I was making was not using document-element. Here's some (+ cool-points 10)

Comment: On a different note - how would you suggest I change this code. Tikkba does mutate the DOM and I know it is not the best way to do it.
I typically make a second pass to reduce the lines of code. It being a personal project I look forward to reducing the lines of code in my project.

Comment: Ah, you've got me now! It depends. In general I would tend to use something like Enlive or Laser for transforming an XML or HTML document, rather than mutating it. The thing is, the output of lacij (as far as I can see) is a java object. So your choice of tikkba here seems pretty sound - I don't see any obvious other way of doing it (unless you can extend lacij in some way to recognize the script tag).

Comment: Oh and one more thing. I had to replace tikkba.dom/svg-ns with org.apache.batik.util.XMLConstants/XLINK_NAMESPACE_URI which is the correct namespace. Otherwise we get "Unknown text/ecmascript" errors